# mysqli_query() expects parameter 3 to be long

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update mysql table with query but it shows

> error - mysqli_query() expects parameter 3 to be long

```
if($money >= 400) {

$query = "UPDATE users SET spam = spam + 1, money = money - 400 WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user'];
$query = "UPDATE users SET score = score + 2500 WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user'];

$update = mysqli_query($conn,$query,$query);
echo 'Spam.exe Upgraded for $400!!';

} else {

// Prints error
echo 'Not enough Money!!';

}
```

Comment: i wanna update it too thats why

Comment: read [mysqli_multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

Comment: why this `$update = mysqli_query($conn,$query,$query);` and why not this `$update = mysqli_query($conn,$query);` ?

Comment: why are passing 2 query parameter, instead use multi query. OR Instead use this 2 times `$update = mysqli_query($conn,$query1);` and `$update2 = mysqli_query($conn,$query2);`

Comment: i have read it but i am not able to understand please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call 2 queries separately like this :

```
if($money >= 400) {

$query1 = "UPDATE users SET spam = spam + 1, money = money - 400 WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user'];
$query2 = "UPDATE users SET score = score + 2500 WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user'];

$update1 = mysqli_query($conn,$query1); // call 1st query
$update2 = mysqli_query($conn,$query2); // call 2nd query
echo 'Spam.exe Upgraded for $400!!';

} else {

// Prints error
echo 'Not enough Money!!';

}
```

Comment: you can also use mysqli_multi_query in MYSQLI... :)

Comment: @devpro, but I guess user was not knowing it. So, I tried to answer in the part in which user was comfortable. Else `mysqli_multi_query` was a good option

Answer (score 1):

just use **[mysqli_multi_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)**, you can run the two update query as a single query using string concadination:

```
$query = "UPDATE users SET spam = spam + 1, money = money - 400 WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user'].";";
$query .= "UPDATE users SET score = score + 2500 WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user'];

mysqli_multi_query($con,$query);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code:

```
$query = "UPDATE users SET spam = spam + 1, money = money - 400 WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user'];
$query1 = "UPDATE users SET score = score + 2500 WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user'];

$update = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$update1 = mysqli_query($conn,$query1);
echo 'Spam.exe Upgraded for $400!!';
```

Answer (score -1):

3rd parameter for `mysqli_query` is `$resultmode`.
See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php.

Just use `mysqli_query($conn,$query).`