# ERRROR PDOStatement::bindParam() expects parameter 3 to be long, string given

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

Hopefully a quick and obvious error on my part, I had a peek through [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35152449/mysqli-query-expects-parameter-3-to-be-long) but could not find question directly related to my question, so forgive me for opening what should be considered a fairly simple question, *but after years of working with mysql the PDO switch is not coming easily*

### What I want to do

Simply insert entered form data to a new row of my table

### Code

**HTML**

```
<form name="animals" id="animals" method="post">
    <label for="animalType">Animal Type: </label>
    <input type="text" required="required" name="animalType" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <label for="animalName">Animal Name:</label>
    <input type="text" required="required" name="animalName" />
    <br />    
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Add</button>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    //here we get the data submitted in form and assign to vars
    $type = $_POST['animalType'];
    $name = $_POST['animalName'];
    //here we are preparing our SQL statment
    $sql = "INSERT INTO animals
            (animal_type, animal_name)
             VALUES
             (?,?)";
    //prepare DB as per above        
    $statement = $db->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindParam("ss", $type, $name);
    $success = $statement->execute();
    if($success){
        echo'Welldone Chuck, Successfully Updated'; 
    }
    else{
        $error = $db->error;
        echo'Whoopsy Doopsy someone made a boopsy, ERROR INFO: $error'; 
    }
    $statement->close();
}
```

**Error:**

> PDOStatement::bindParam() expects parameter 3 to be long, string given
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound'

**Possible Reason For Error?**

Dreamweaver as I am typing brings up a help function, as it often does `(paramNo, Param, ParamType)` should I specify that I am binding 2 parameters here? (which I tried but same error as above though.)

**Table**

[image]

**Thanks a million**

Comment: PDO's `bindParam` does NOT have `ss` and is mysqli_ prepared statements syntax. Did you not read the manual??

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sorry when I remove that I get error `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens`

Comment: @Fred-ii- and no I did NOT as I am working as per my university handbook, which is horribly confusing

Comment: @Fred-ii- The thing with the manual is it can be very hard for novices to understand sometimes, but thanks for comment

Comment: Well that handbook either has errors or you're using mysqli_ to connect with and didn't notice the underscore between `bind` and `param`, should that be the case. Either way, you can't mix MySQL APIs.

Comment: @Fred-ii- YES, I was just messaging you to ask about that, it has an underscore in my book, which I overlooked

Comment: and there we have it. Problem solved. Use `bind_param` and you'll be good to go ;-)

Comment: I'll also bet my last dollar that the person who gave you an answer, might notice my comments here and will change their answer *lol* and should, because it's wrong.

Comment: @Fred-ii- U prob would have won..Is that why I am getting the ` Call to undefined method PDOStatement::bind_param()`  error now?  :-( (crying out loud) I am using PDO to connect.... `$dsn ='mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tim';
$uName = 'root';
$pWord= '';
$options= array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: ok now I don't know where to throw myself *lol* - You say the book contains the underscore but does that book also tell you to use the same API to connect with? It seems I have to delete my comments in the answer below now, as you're connecting with PDO but now using mysqli_ syntax. Replace it with what the guy gave you below. The duplicate though, still stands.

Comment: @Fred-ii- No kidding mate ill upload you a GIF of the example code in book, gimmie a second

Comment: Better place: the manual on prepared statements http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements and error checking http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- no offence First check and then comment :) it would be nice. Read the post it is mentioned clearly  `"PDOStatement::bindParam()" & "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException"`  If the statement was was having mysqli connection it might have thrown some things else instead of PDO error (y)

Comment: @NareshKumar given the unknown API that the OP was using from the start, my comments were relevant. When I found out what he was using, I removed my comments. So had I known from the start and knew exactly which animal(s) we were dealing with, I wouldn't have posted those comments. I feel I wasn't in the wrong from the start.

Comment: ok I'm out of this question. Sorry Timothy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
$statement = $db->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindParam("ss", $type, $name);
```

with

```
$statement = $db->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindParam(1, $type, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindParam(2, $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

For more information, refer to the manual [PDO Bind Param](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)